# ¿Función en Java que reciba una lista de objetos de varios tipos y devuelva uno de sus elementos según un criterio de búsqueda?

Tags: java, herencia, polimorfismo

Tengo una serie de listas de objetos que extienden de otro que tiene, entre otros,  un atributo "*esNuevo*" con su método "*getEsNuevo()*"

Me preguntaba si se podría hacer una única función o método que recibiera como parámetro una de esas listas e independientemente del tipo de objetos pudiera recorrerla, buscar el primer elemento de dicha lista que tuviera establecido ese atributo a "true", y devolverlo. Diría que no, pero si se pudiera me ahorraría mucho trabajo...

**EDITO:** Intento añadir una función tipo para uno de los objetos que tengo, para que sirva de referencia:

```
public DetalleEmpleado obtenerDetalleEmpleadoNuevo(ArrayList<DetalleEmpleado> listaDetalles) {
    for (DetalleEmpleado detEmp : listaDetalles) {
        if (detEmp.isNuevo())
            return detEmp;
    }
    return null;
}
```

La idea sería hacer un método similar a este, pero que devolvería un "objeto" del mismo tipo de la lista que hemos recibido. Y no veo cómo codificar esto...

Por si sirve, todos los objetos y listas que estarían implicados extienden de una clase abstracta que tiene ese método, llamada "Comparador". Pongo aquí un segmento de la misma:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class Comparador<T> {
    /**
     * Indica si es nuevo 
     */
    protected boolean nuevo=false;
/**resto de código...*/
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Si getEsNuevo() esta definido en la clase de la que todos heredan se puede. También se puede si tododas las clases implementan una interface comúm que tenga el método getEsNuevo().

Comment: Pues @pablo, he intentado escribir este método, pero con mis conocimientos no he sabido cómo especificar el parámetro "genérico" de la lista de "objetos", y ya me ha entrado la duda de si es viable algo así...

Comment: Es viable, sí, pero hace falta un código base sobre el que ayudarte.

Comment: Tal vez la clase Object te pueda ser util, te paso un link que explica un poco acerca de eso [Programación orientada a objetos: la clase Object](https://rootear.com/desarrollo/poo-clase-object-java)

Answer (score 2):

Usando Generics puedes crear una clase que trate la lista:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class BuscadorNuevo<T extends Comparador> {

    public Optional<T> buscarEnLista(List<T> lista) {
        return lista.stream().filter(Comparador::getEsNuevo).findFirst();
    }

    public static void main() {
        List<DetalleEmpleado> x = getListaEmpleados();
        BuscadorNuevo<DetalleEmpleado> buscadorNuevo = new BuscadorNuevo<>();
        buscadorNuevo.buscarEnLista(x).ifPresent(UnaClaseQueTrataElNuevo::hacerAlgoConElEmpleado);
    }
}

public void hacerAlgoConElEmpleado(DetalleEmpleado empleado){
    //hacer algo
}
```

Si tuvieras otra clase

```
public class DetalleDirector extends Comparador{
}
```

harías:

```
public static void main() {
            List<DetalleDirector > x = getListaDirectores();
            BuscadorNuevo<DetalleDirector > buscadorNuevo = new BuscadorNuevo<>();
            buscadorNuevo.buscarEnLista(x).ifPresent(UnaClaseQueTrataElNuevo::hacerAlgoConElDirector);
        }

public void hacerAlgoConElDirector(DetalleDirector director){
    //hacer algo
}
```